# Wordpress custom menu using Ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress, forms

I am creating a website that has a huge number of forms that are called from a dynamically created menu. There may be a number of other pages on the site that are basic HTML layouts. I was thinking to use Wordpress as the controller for my site. That way I do not have to replicate the Wordpress layout features. I would need to do the following:

1. Have Wordpress get the contents of the menu using AJAX which would
   return the descriptions and the links to the pages.
2. On selection of an option from the menu open the page in an iframe.

Is this even possible and, if so, where would I start?

Comment: _open the page in an iframe_ which page would this be then?

Comment: Wordpress is an open CMS. You need to build theme and use WP functions to load those menus